# react native memory leak location

Tags: react-native, memory-leaks

I am working on a project with react native. Upon login it takes to home screen of products, while Im receiving  memory leak error as,

```
ERROR  Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in LoginScreen (at SceneView.tsx:126)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:118)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:210)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:280)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:278)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in CardSheet (at Card.tsx:557)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at Card.tsx:536)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:14)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:530)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at Card.tsx:526)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:520)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:218)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:649)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at src/index.native.tsx:114)
    in Screen (at Screens.tsx:37)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:642)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at src/index.native.tsx:145)
    in ScreenContainer (at Screens.tsx:20)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:561)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Background.tsx:13)
    in Background (at CardStack.tsx:559)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:437)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:430)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:429)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:118)
    in Unknown (at createStackNavigator.tsx:117)
    in StackNavigator (at auth-navigator.tsx:61)
    in AuthNavigator (at root-navigator.tsx:36)
```

I have gone through the error but couldnt identify which line of code giving error.

How to identify from above which line of code in any particular file causes the problem ?
Is there a way to find out such issues(with debug) ?

Comment: The most common cause of this is useEffects or animations that are still working when the screen gets popped off the nav stack. Make sure you're removing listeners and canceling animations when the screen is blurred.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue, i was enabling a button after login(changes to another navigator) inside an async function which was executing even after screen change.
Like,

```
async Login()
{
if(auth==="success")
gotoScreen2() 
enableLoginButton()// this executes while in 2nd screen
}
```

Hope somebody will find it helpful.